# Leaflet Draw Popup text unselectable in Chrome

Tags: leaflet

I have a map here: http://maps.gcc.tas.gov.au/measure.html

I have some simple popups happening, and it's working well. But, I can't select the text for markers when using Chrome or Firefox.

This does work in IE, funnily enough. What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

Your popup is inheriting this style from somewhere:

`-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;`

You should add some code in your css to set:

`div.leaflet-popup-content p {
  -webkit-user-select: auto;
  -moz-user-select: auto;
}`

Beware that this selection could be overridden elsewhere, so you will might need to change it!